# Random spawning in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

Hi I am making my first unity game in 2D and I have this code now. I have 3 different GameObjects (call them a, b , c) in the array arrows and i would want to know which one of them is spawned ( so i can use it in another function) and delete the previous one from the scene. Now it just spawns one GameObject on another every 5 seconds and I don't know which one of them did it randomly spawn. Any idea?

```
public GameObject[] arrows;
public float interval = 5;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnArrow());
}
public IEnumerator SpawnArrow()
{
    WaitForSeconds delay = new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject prefab = arrows[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length)];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);
        yield return delay;


    }
}`
```

Comment: You just use the object you created as a parameter. you put a 
 `YourOtherFunction(clone)`in the while loop. If that is not what you are looking for you need to provide more deatail about what you are trying to do. Include the other function too in your code example.

Comment: Also, if you are asking about Unity you need to put the [tag:Unity3d] tag on your question. Otherwise you may get answers that are not appropriate to use on Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep track of what objects you instantiated you could create a `List` of `GameObject` and then when you instantiate an object you can add it in the `List`. Then you can use any `GameObject` in that list to do whatever you need.

```
public GameObject[] arrows;
public float interval = 5;
private List<GameObject> myObjects = new List<GameObject>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnArrow());
}
public IEnumerator SpawnArrow()
{
    WaitForSeconds delay = new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject prefab = arrows[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length)];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);

        //Add the object to the list
        myObjects.Add(clone);

        yield return delay;


    }
}
```

And for spawning object like that it would be better to use `InvokeRepeating`, you can pass it the repeat rate and when you want it to start. [More information on InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

This is how it could look like with `InvokeRepeating`

```
public GameObject[] arrows;
public float interval = 5;
private List<GameObject> myObjects = new List<GameObject>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnArrow", 0f, interval);
}

void SpawnArrow()
{
    //Check if there's something in the list
    if (myObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        //Destroy the last object in the list.
        Destroy(myObjects.Last());

        //Remove it from the list.
        myObjects.RemoveAt(myObjects.Count - 1);
    }

    GameObject prefab = arrows[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length)];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);

    //Add the object to the list
    myObjects.Add(clone);

}
```

You can destroy the last spawned object in the list by doing `Destroy(myObjects.Last());` it will return the last object in your list and destroy it. You should then also remove it from the list `myObjects.RemoveAt(myObjects.Count - 1);`

Comment: Thanks. How to I know which object spawned last (i would like to use it like: if object a spawned then... ) and how do i know which object spawned before it so i can destroy it from the scene? (i am using this InvokeRepeating code now) :D

Comment: @KlemenŠkrlj I added at the end of my answer how you could do it.

Comment: And where in the code do i put this two lines? (I know.. I am a noob) It said that i have to add System.Linq and when i run it i says:InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[GameObject] (IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: @KlemenŠkrlj I edited my answer could you try it like that and you need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your script.

Comment: Just a final question since you know everything: How do i check which object did it spawned? How do i implement this into  an if statement?

Comment: @KlemenŠkrlj You can know what object spawned by checking it's name. Your `clone` value will hold the gameobject that just spawned so you could do `clone.name` and then compare it to a certain value. And it would be easier to help if you posted a new question with exactly what you want to do in detail :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how much this will help, but have you tried making each individual arrow an object, and then just returning that object to the method you need it.

```
public GameObject SpawnArrow(<some params>){
    GameObject prefab = arrows[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length)];
    while(interval > 0){
        if(interval = 0){
            prefab = arrows[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length)];
            GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);
        } else {
            System.Threading.Thread.sleep(1000) // wait for the second.
            interval = interval - 1;
        }
    }
    return prefab;
}
```

IDK Unity - Never used it, but you need to either rewrite the function to return the arrow object (Not the delay object) to the calling function. Of course the above code should be considered NOT working and just pseudo code as I do not use unity. But the gist is just find a better way to spawn an arrow in a method that can return it.

Comment: That's not how it works in Unity, the `Instantiate` will spawn a `GameObject` in the current scene. What `yield return delay;` does is wait the amount of time specified before continuing.

Comment: I edited it again - However I don't know unity, just C# I explained this in the edit.

Comment: You never, ever, ever, ever call `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` from inside a Unity project.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Thanks for the information! As I said in my post - I do not use unity - so the code should be looked at as pseudo code. I appreciate the information and will keep that in mind!

Comment: @MitchellUrgero You should not answer a question if you are not sure, if you don't know Unity then your answer may confuse the OP or it can be a wrong answer

Comment: @Sxntk Although  you would be right - I do know enough about C# to at least try and help (And I would have used a comment but I am a very new, and light user to stackoverflow so I cannot) so I unfortunately used an answer :( I will try to do better next time. Thank you!